# if: $\log_{a}{ax}+2\log_{a^2}{ax}+3\log_{a^3}{ax}...+10\log_{a}{a^{10}x}$ what is x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> if: $\log_{a}{ax}+2\log_{a^2}{ax}+3\log_{a^3}{ax}...+10\log_{a}{a^{10}x}=110$ what is x?

I've simplified the equation to: $\log_{a}{a^{385}x^{55}}=110$

but then I have no clue what to do afterwards

Comment: Where is the $=$ in the earlier equation?

Comment: $\log _a a^{110}=110$, so $a^{110}=a^{385}x^{55}$

Comment: Also, did you mean to make $a^{10}$ the base of the last logarithm, and $ax$ the number you are taking the log of? I was only able to work off the second equation. Also, please add the equality of the first equation, like @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\log_{a}(a^{385}x^{55})=110$:

$$\log_{a}(a^{385})+\log_{a}(x^{55})=110$$
$$385+\log_{a}(x^{55})=110$$
$$\log_{a}(x^{55})=-275$$
$$x^{55}=a^{-275}$$
$$(x^{55})^{\frac{1}{55}}=(a^{-275})^{\frac{1}{55}}=x^{55 \cdot \frac{1}{55}}=a^{-275 \cdot \frac{1}{55}}=x=a^{-\frac{275}{55}}=a^{-5}$$

Therefore, we have:

$$x=a^{-5}$$